# on text created event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I determine when specific text created in the html document?

I know how to determine when element created by its id or class `$("div").on('DOMNodeInserted' , '.myclass', function(){...});`, but not by text in element.

Comment: what do you mean by specific text?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: Events? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_events.htm

Comment: Inside function please check if the htm/text/val is the text you want or not. A high level "if" may do the trick.

Comment: On button click, text message is added to DIV, I wanted to check if this text equal to what i want.

I found a solution in below answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".checkout_coupon .button" ).click(function() {
    $("div.woocommerce").on('DOMNodeInserted', 'div.woocommerce-message:contains("success message")', function()
    { 
        //the "success message" found in div.woocommerce
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer should also include an actual explanation of the code you have provided.